# phantomjs: command not found

Tags: linux, phantomjs

`man phantomjs` даёт нужный результат.
`which phantomjs` выдаёт:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

`whereis phantomjs` выдаёт:

```
phantomjs: /usr/lib/phantomjs /usr/share/man/man1/phantomjs.1.gz
```

`sudo find / -name phantomjs` выдаёт:

```
/usr/share/doc/phantomjs  
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs  
/usr/lib/phantomjs  
/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs
```

`sudo apt-get install phantomjs` выдаёт:

```
phantomjs is already the newest version (2.1.1+dfsg-2)
```

Но при попытке в терминале запустить `phantomjs -v` выдаётся:

```
phantomjs: command not found
```

День сплошных неудач.

Answer (score 0):

Простая переустановка помогла.

```
sudo apt-get purge phantomjs && sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```